# Document Metadata in MS CRM and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, dynamics-crm

We are integrating MS CRM with SharePoint and we want that when the documents with Metadata are uploaded in CRM then  those metadata to be available as column value both in CRM and SharePoint. Is this even possible?